# Function wrapper that prints the result

Tags: c++, performance, beginner, programming-challenge

(English)
I was recently challenged to make a simple program that does the following:

Function f accepts as a parameter a function g, which returns a value. Function f must return a function h which returns and prints the value that function g returns.

After some research I got the solution and the program was successful, but I wonder if the code is done in the best way. I would appreciate immensely a critique.

This is the code:

Hace poco me retaron a realizar un programa sencillo que realiza lo siguiente:

La función f acepta como parámetro una función g, la cual regresa un valor. La función f debe de regresar una función h la cual regresa e imprime el valor que regresa la función g.

Luego de investigar un poco conseguí la solución y el programa resulto exitoso, pero me pregunto si el código esta hecho de la mejor manera. Agradecería inmensamente una critica.

Este es el código:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

auto g() // Función que regresara el valor principal
{
    return 123;
}

template <class FT>

auto f(FT* fref) // Función que recibira una referencia de una función
{
    return [=]() -> auto // Regresa una función creada a partir de "fref"
    {
        cout << fref() << endl;
        return fref();
    };
}

int main()
{
    auto h = f(&g); // Llamando la función f pasando la referencia de la función g
    auto resultado = h();
    cout << resultado << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please describe your question in English.

Comment: Already done :)

Comment: Please also update the title :)

Comment: In function `f`, what if the return object of the input `fref` without operator<< overloading? Could you describe what kind of particular purpose for using function `f`? Please [give an explanation of what these code does. The more detail, the better.](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: What kind of *programming challenge* is this?

Comment: "which returns [...] the value that function g returns" Does `g` always return the same? Or should `h` always return the value that `g` would return if called once at the beginning of `f`? The task is not clear enough imo. (It probably is meant as a simple "logging-wrapper". Then it's almost ok - see greybeards answer. And if that's the case, is it meant to also work for functions with arguments?)

Comment: I am in the Close Question Queue and I am voting to leave the question open. The problem with the question is that the title is not in English, other than that this seems to be a good question asking for a code review.

Comment: @greybeard I was reading a C++ book and my brother wanted to know if I was really learning, and he challenged me :3.

Comment: @BlameTheBits True, it could only be used in functions that do not accept arguments.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I see one substantial problem with your implementation:

`f()` calls `fref()` *twice* - bad enough if each call consumes considerable resources,
probably **plain wrong** where the call has *side effects*.

(The funny part is `main()` introducing a variable to hold the result *without* need.)

Answer (score 1):

`using namespace std;` is a harmful habit you'd do well to shake off.  It's less effort to write `std::` in the four places you use it (two if you stop flushing with every newline) anyway.

Instead of passing a pointer to your function, it's probably simpler to pass the invocable itself.  That allows `g` to be something other than a plain function - perhaps a `std::function` or some other object with `operator()`.
It's quite reasonable for the template argument to deduce to be a pointer type, so that won't affect the current usage.  A function name decays to a pointer to the function, so `g` would be as good as `&g` anyway.

Instead of a catch-all capture, I think it's better to be specific: replace `[=]` with `[fref]`.

The `-> auto` return type will always return *by value*, but if the wrapped function returns a reference, we should be returning the same reference, rather than a copy of the referent.  That would be `-> decltype(fref(declval(args)...))` or more simply, `-> decltype(auto)`.

It seems unnecessary for `main()` to also print the result, when that's what the function itself does.

Simplified thus, we get:

```
template<class F>
auto f(F fref)
{
    return [fref] -> decltype(auto) {
        auto&& result = fref();
        std::cout << result << '\n';
        return result;
    };
}
```

We should probably constrain `F` to be something we can invoke:

```
#include <concepts>

template<typename F>
auto f(F fref)
    requires std::invocable<F>
{
    return [fref] -> decltype(auto) {
        auto&& result = fref();
        std::cout << result << '\n';
        return result;
    };
}
```

Perhaps we should be passing the output stream as argument to `h()`, given the problem statement didn't say which stream to print to.

What about functions that take arguments?  It wasn't specified that `g()` would be a function of no arguments.  Let's pass arguments through, and supply the stream at call time:

```
#include <concepts>
#include <ostream>
#include <utility>
    
template<typename F>
auto f(F fref)
{
    return [fref](std::ostream& os, auto&&... args)
        -> decltype(auto)
    {
        auto&& result = fref(std::forward<decltype(args)>(args)...);
        os << result << '\n';
        return std::forward<decltype(result)>(result);
    };
}

int main()
{
    auto const h = f(g);
    h(std::cout);
}
```

Comment: You're thinking of ` decltype(auto)` which is specifically for this situation.  It preserves the value category.  See https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/auto under **perfect forwarding**.

Comment: And in fact, I already edited to use `decltype(auto)` - but looks like I missed it in a couple of spots.